# jQuery if hover / if not anymore

Tags: jquery

i have ve a little JS Script. If i hover over an "a" Element the div.overlay is showing.
But how can i say "if i am not anymore on the a Element set the display:block to none; ?

```
$(function() {

    var docHeight = $(document).height();

    $("body").append("<div id='overlay'></div>");

    $(".navbar-default .navbar-nav a").hover(function() {
       $("#overlay")
            .height(docHeight)
            .css({
                'display': 'block',
                'top': 80,
        });
    });

});
```

My css for this div

```
.overlay {
  display: none;
  z-index: 98;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Comment: Can you please create a fiddle for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Signature of [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/#hover1) is

```
$( selector ).hover( handlerIn, handlerOut )
```

> Bind two handlers to the matched elements, to be executed when the mouse pointer enters and leaves the elements.

Hide your div in the `handlerOut`(A function to execute when the mouse pointer leaves the element.), In the `handlerOut` function you can use `$("#overlay").hide();` to hide the element.

Use

```
$(".navbar-default .navbar-nav a").hover(function () {
    $("#overlay")
        .height(docHeight)
        .css({
            'display': 'block',
            'top': 80,
        });
}, function () {
    $("#overlay").hide();
});
```